# in Python in Maya, partial forces the first argrument to be 'False' instead of its default value

Tags: python, function, maya, partial

In Autodesk Maya I am using the functools partial function for when my UI needs to trigger functions.  But when the function has a default value for its first argument, partial always sends a False (or 0) value, overriding the default.  No arguments besides the first are affected.

Why does this occur, and how do I get around it?  Here's some example code to clarify it better:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
from functools import partial

def MyFunction(X=5,Y=6):
    print("The first number should be 5, and it is "+str(X) +"\nThe second number should be 6 and it is "+str(Y))


def PartialProblemUI():
    ##remove the window if it exists
    if mc.window("PartialProblem_Window", ex=True): mc.deleteUI("PartialProblem_Window")
    ##start of the window UI
    mc.window("PartialProblem_Window", title="Partial Problem",w=120,h=65, tlb=True,s=False)   
    form=mc.formLayout()   

    c=mc.button("UI_Btn_PartialProblem",l="Partial Problem",c=partial(MyFunction),w=150,h=40)
    mc.formLayout(form,e=True,attachForm=[(c,"left",21),((c,"top",5))])
    
    ##show the window
    mc.showWindow("PartialProblem_Window")    
    
    ####force the window to be a certain size
    mc.window("PartialProblem_Window", e=True ,w=200,h=115)     

PartialProblemUI()
```

The result I get back is:

> The first number should be 5, and it is False The second number should
> be 6 and it is 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the callback of the `mc.button()` function always receives some args from the button command and the first argument is replaced. You can solve it by using

```
def MyFunction(*args, X=5, Y=6):
```

as function call. This catches all normal arguments and does not touch the keyword agruments.

Comment: Thanks, that works great in this case. I had mistakenly thought that when *args is used, it was supposed to be at the end.   If I need to have a required argument without a default value, do I add that before *args?  like this:  def MyFunction( Z,*args, X=5, Y=6 ):

Comment: Also, this only seems to work in Python 3. So its fine in Maya 2022, but not in Maya 2019. What is needed in Python 2?  I got around it by putting a junk variable at the beginning, like this:   def MyFunction( SacrificialArgument, X=5, Y=6):    but that seems really sloppy.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this only works in Python3. But you could use `def MyFunction(dummy, X=5, Y=6)` what catches the first argument